# Cron generating a lot of process causing the server to hang (Magento 2.0.2)

Tags: cron, crontab, apache2, magento-2.0.2

I have a VM running ubuntu with no problem:

> Tasks: 124 total,   1 running, 123 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
>
> %Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
>
> MiB Mem:   992.473 total,  800.410 used,  192.062 free,   87.496 buffers
>
> MiB Swap: 4095.996 total,  124.945 used, 3971.051 free.   95.289 cached Mem

However, if cron jobs are enabled it seems it run fine just for a couple of hours:

> server# ps -ef | grep -i php | grep -v grep | wc -l
>
> 3

even though the server is totally idle, after some hours (randomly) those jobs stop completing but they are still being raised:

> server# ps -ef | grep -i php | grep -v grep | wc -l
>
> 279

On magento user's cron I have:

> */1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/html/bin/magento cron:run >> /var/log/magento/magento.cron.log&
>
> */1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/html/update/cron.php >> /var/log/magento/update.cron.log&
>
> */1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/log/magento/setup.cron.log&

I used to have **memory_limit = 128M** on php.ini then increased to **512M** but didn´t work (had apache rebooted).

Logs:

**magento.cron.log**

> Ran jobs by schedule.

**update.cron.log**

> Cron readiness check failed

**setup.cron.log**

> PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46)
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>      with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

I usually reboot the server since it stop responding through ssh.
Any idea?
Thanks!